# Try to add widgets dynamically in another thread PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

I have some QDialog with some initial widgets. I try to run a QThread to add others widgets after my api request but I can't.

`main.py`:

```
class Lobby(QDialog):
    signal_api_response = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, _token, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI() # build initial ui

        self.mythread= MyThread('arg test')
        self.mythread.new_signal.connect(self.response_my_api)
        self.mythread.start()

        self.showFullScreen()

    @pyqtSlot(dict)
    def response_worker_mychar(self, response):
        print(response)
        # build dynamic widget (not creating new widgets here)
        self.some_slot = QLabel('zzzzz', self)
        self.some_slot.move(10, 10)
        self.some_slot.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        self.some_slot.setStyleSheet(f"border: 2px solid red;color:white;")
```

Thread class:

```
class MyThread(QThread):
    new_signal = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, token=None, parent=None):
        super(QThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.token = token

    def run(self):
        response = get_blabla_api(self.token)
        self.new_signal.emit(response)
```

QThread is working but it doesn't create new widgets (QLabel, ...). I tried to change an existing widget and it worked, but creating others didn't work.

I don't get an error, but it doesn't create the widgets.

Note: the function where I create these dynamic widgets after the signal emit works, it just doesn't work using QThread. I'm using QThread because as I make a request in the api, PyQt freezes.

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre], specifically the code that attempts to create those widgets.

Comment: Your question is still a bit confusing. You said that you need to add new widgets, but then you also say "I didn't need to create the other widgets".  What do you actually need to do? Do you just want to update a pixmap on a label? Or do you want to add *new* labels (and pixmaps) every time the thread emits its signal? Also, you should use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: Sorry for confused question. I need to add new QLabel every emit event. I don't want to use layouts. I create all QDialog without, why I need to use now? @musicamante

Comment: Because not using layout managers is always discouraged, unless you *really* know what you're doing. Most of the times they are avoided just for lack of knowledge or experience and, most importantly, awareness of what happens if they are not used: for instance, system styling and scaling can result in widgets that become partially hidden, overlapping or not usable. 99% of the times a dev says "I don't need layouts" they realize sooner or later that they cannot ignore them. The remaining 1% is because they *do* know how layout managers actually work and are completely aware of their situation.

Comment: I created a class to calc all widgets to be responsive. I tested in differents sizes and works.  I need to use Layouts to work with QThreads (to explicity add new widgets to layout)?

Comment: For instance, if you knew more about layouts, you also knew that adding a widget to a layout of an already shown parent automatically shows the new widget, while simply creating a child widget on an already shown parent requires to explicitly call `show()` or `setVisible(True)`. The problem has absolutely *nothing* to do with threads: have you considered the font metrics and system scaling, the size hints and size policies of each widget? It's not enough to "test in different sizes". Also, setting instance attributes for dynamically created objects is pointless, especially considering what ->

Comment: -> you're trying to achieve: if you really want to manually set the geometries of all widgets, how can you access objects for which you're constantly overwriting their reference? The moment you set again `self.some_slot`, you lose the reference to the previous QLabel, and any attempt to adjust the geometry will become unnecessarily complex. Interestingly enough, if layout managers were properly used, you wouldn't need any of that at all.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks, using `.show()` solved the question!

Comment: I put a minimally viable example only. My project is extremely more complex than that. I was just wondering about dynamically creating widgets in another thread. Thank you, solved here!